# firebase emulator queries vs firestore database queries

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have been recently building my first project with firebase, and have been using the firebase emulators for development. I have added the functionality to daisy-chain queries as filters (hasFreeEntry, parking etc) and also sort the results (by name, rating etc). This works perfectly on the emulator, allowing compound queries and sorting, however when moving to the hosted production db, I found that compound queries don't work.

After doing some research it seems that this isn't really supported- or at least you have to create an index. There would have to be a lot of index's created for the functionality I want.

What I don't really understand is why the filters worked perfectly with the emulators but not the actual db. Is the point of the emulator not to mimic the behaviour of the production db, or am I missing something?

Using the filters on the production db results in a 500 error.

Comment: This is a known behavior of the emulator.